# Simplifying redirect in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have redirects:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/thema(.*)$ https://www.newurl.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/stichpunkt(.*)$ https://newurl.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/author(.*)$ https://www.newurl.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/2023(.*)$ https://www.newurl.com [R=301,L]
```

is there a way to simplify these into one line?

Comment: Aside: many-to-one redirects to the homepage like this are never a best practice.

Comment: @MrWhite?Why?Would it be better to redirect to 404?

Comment: Yes, (but not literally "redirect" to a 404). Multiple redirects to the homepage are going to be seen as a "soft-404" by Google (and will _eventually_ drop the pages from the search results), but they are also confusing for users when they see different content than they are expecting (and bounce). If these (old) URLs have not moved to a different location then a _custom_ 404 response that displays a meaningful message to users (perhaps suggesting alternative links/content) is a far better user experience. And gives search engines the "correct" response.

Comment: @MrWhite I need to disable category, tag, author and date archives in Wordpress, so it is not about redirecting because urls have changed but instead to disable the achive pages. What would you recommend?

Comment: Related to my earlier comment, see the following questions on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104668/can-301-redirects-to-homepage-solve-404-errors-in-google-search-console / https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49395/redirect-incomplete-url-to-index-page / https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51317/302-redirect-to-homepage-from-removed-pages

Comment: I've posted an answer with regards to "disabling the archive pages".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to disable category, tag, author and date archives in Wordpress

This should really be done in WordPress itself. Otherwise WP is still going to generate and publish these URLs (eg. Sitemap, RSS feed, etc.).

Otherwise, if `.htaccess` is your only option then you should serve a 404, rather than redirect to the homepage. Whilst a redirect to the homepage is likely to be treated as a soft-404 by Google (and possibly other search engines) it runs the risk of being indexed under these "archive" URLs (and accessible with a `site:` search).

For example, at the top of the root `.htaccess` file (before any existing WP directives):

```
# Whatever your custom 404 page is (could be WordPress)
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Force a 404 for "category, tag, author and date archives
RewriteRule (^|/)(thema|author|stichpunkt|2\d{3})(/|$) - [R=404]
```

`2\d{4}` matches any 4 digit year (in the 2000's).

The regex matches any of those "words" only when they occur as a whole path segement (not partial matches).

`R=404` - This is not a "redirect" (despite the use of the `R` flag). The 404 error document is served via an internal subrequest and a 404 HTTP response code is set on the initial response. If these URLs have previously been indexed then consider changing this to a "410 Gone" instead, ie. `R=410` or simply `G` (shorthand flag).

Comment: when you say this should be done by WP itself, are you talking about doing it this way? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69948/get-rid-of-wordpress-category-tag-and-author-archives

Comment: @maw Yes, something like that. (Although slight concern... that question is rather old and the plugin mentioned has not been updated in 11 years, so might not work with recent versions of WP?)

Comment: I did not mean to use the plugin, but the code snippet provided that uses         $wp_query->set_404(); It still works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple alternation with `|`:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(thema|author|stichpunkt|2023) https://www.newurl.com [R=301,L]
```

You don't need to capture parts that you don't need to refer back to, so I removed the `()` around the `.*`. Around the alternation they are still needed so even if you are not interested in capturing that part, otherwise it would not be clear where the first value starts and the last one ends.

And you don't need to match `.*$` either, you can just leave of the `$` that anchors this pattern at the end.

Comment: Should not need `^.*/` either by that same logic, if you just demand a leading `/`, it will also match `foobar/thema` etc.